# How does one "authenticate" a bitcoin user?

Tags: authentication

What is the minimum standard for authenticating a bitcoin user. Would it be enough, for instance to verify that someone named "Tom Au" will answer to that name at this email address? Or are more detailed checks required?

**Edit:** Authentication would mean that I am what I say I am, that I am a human being and not a robot,and that I can do what I purport to be doing (trading Bitcoin).

Is there a public, or central registry for computer users?

In this event, would something as strong as ["hashing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) be needed for data storage and retrieval?

Would a [web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) concept work for the bitcoin community?

Comment: "Authenticate" can mean a lot of things, and I'm unaware of any standards in this direction.  In what sense would checks be *required*?  Required by whom?  Perhaps you should explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is the same problem that CAPTCHAs want to solve and there is not a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are different KYC (Know Your Customer) laws in different jurisdictions, but generally it takes information that is difficult or very time consuming to falsify. License/ID scans, utility bills, and SSNs are examples

Suggesting "hashing" as a KYC solution suggests you do not know what hashing is (unless you were referring to the way a server should store such confidential information). I suggest you use the search function or explore bitcoin wikipedia to learn more.